# Mysql query to get inserted user name and updated user name with select query?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have two tables `products` and `users` with fields,

**Products**

```
id
name
insertedUserID
ipdatedUserID
```

**Users**

```
id
name
```

I am trying to get the the product details with the data,

```
ProductID
ProductName
InsertedUser
UpdatedUser
```

For this I am using this mysql query,

```
SELECT Products.id as ProductID,Products.name as ProductName, Users.name as InsertedUser 
LEFT JOIN Users ON Products.insertedUserID = Users.id
```

This query is working only for Inserted user only. How can I get updated user with this query?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you want to get both data or and condition so . if you want to both condition data then use **union all**

```
SELECT Products.id as ProductID,Products.name as ProductName, Users.name as InsertedUser 
LEFT JOIN Users ON Products.insertedUserID = Users.id

union all 
SELECT Products.id as ProductID,Products.name as ProductName, Users.name as InsertedUser 
LEFT JOIN Users ON Products.ipdatedUserID = Users.id
```

or if you want to only single condition then

```
SELECT Products.id as ProductID,Products.name as ProductName, Users.name as InsertedUser 
    LEFT JOIN Users ON Products.insertedUserID = Users.id and Products.ipdatedUserID = Users.id
```

hope it will help you

Comment: I suspect what is needed here: `LEFT JOIN Users ON Products.insertedUserID = Users.id and Products.ipdatedUserID = Users.id` is "OR", not "and".